# Check if a filename is a folder or a file

Tags: ruby, file

I have a little piece of Ruby code:

```
files.each do |file|
  FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(target))    
  FileUtils.cp_r(file, target, :verbose => true)
end
```

I would like to add a check like

```
if file is a folder
  # do this
if file is a file
  # do that
```

How do I implement in Ruby?

Comment: @Jay Erm, this is Ruby, not Python.

Comment: oh, oops, I  always mix those two up

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can use `File.directory?("name")` and/or `File.file?("name")`.

Comment: Much appreciated! I knew there had to be a method for this. Dir.glob works a bit TOO well :)

Answer (score 2):

Also a good idea to check out [`Pathname#directory?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-directory-3F) and [`Pathname#file?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-file-3F)